# Kotlin pause chronometer at different times

Tags: android, kotlin, chronometer

Im trying to develop an app with a chronometer in kotlin and I need to do several things when te chrono achives some conditions, but I can't do it and I don't know why

This is the setOnChronometerTickListener of my app

```
chrono?.setOnChronometerTickListener {
        if (chrono?.base == 180000L && !inPriority) {
            startStopChrono()
            showWinner()
        } else if (chrono?.base? == 30000L && inPriority) {
            println("EEEEEEEEE")
            startStopChrono()
            showWinner()
        }
    }
```

The problem is when the chrono is in 30 seconds and the condition is true, don't run the methods, and also with the 3 minutes condition

Thanks everyone

Comment: what is inPriority ? Could you show relevant code?

Comment: Is a boolean that changes if I press a button, but I also tried without the inPriority and it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you shouldn't use base, here is the solution:

```
chrono?.setOnChronometerTickListener {
    val elapsed: Long = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - it.base
    if (elapsed >= 180000L) {
        println("Elapsed 3 minutes")
    } else if (elapsed >= 30000L) {
        println("Elapsed 30 seconds")
    }
}
```

According to [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer#getBase()) **getBase()** return time from **setBase()**, if not set it will return **SystemClock.elapsedRealtime** as time base.